# Get scroll position of webview in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, webview, uiwebview

I'm trying to get the scroll position from a webview in swift.  I want to obtain the position when scrolling.  Everytime I start scrolling I would like to get the position of the current scroll and the height of the total scroll.  How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

The scroll view associated with the `WKWebView` and 
`UIWebView`

you can get webView total scroll `contentSize` as follow

```
webView.scrollView.contentSize
```

current scroll position

```
webView.scrollView.contentOffset
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

ScrollView `contentOffset` defines the point of origin of the content view

```
let x_OffsetValue = webView.scrollView.contentOffset.x

let y_OffsetValue = webView.scrollView.contentOffset.y
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can get scroll position of UIWebview:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.contentOffset.y - scrollView.frame.size.height < 120 {
            print("the end")
        } else if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 120 {
            print("the beginning")
        }
    }
```